# Numpy: Why can'I assign a matrix to another matrix's indexed part?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, variable-assignment

Why can't I assign value of an indexed part of matrix from another matrix? Let's see the code example below:

```py
n, m = 5, 10
X = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, n))
indices = np.random.randint(0, m, (n,))

res1 = np.zeros((m, m))
res2 = np.zeros((m, m))
res3 = np.zeros((m, m))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        res1[indices[i], indices[j]] = X[i, j]

res2[:n, :n] = X # ========================================================
(res2[:n, :n] == X).all() # ===============================================
# True (assign to continuous blocks is ok)

res2[indices, ...][:, indices] = X  # directly index from array and assign value
(res2 == res1).all()
# False, res2 stays all-zero

row_mat, col_mat = np.meshgrid(indices, indices)[::-1]
points_arr = np.stack([np.ravel(row_mat), np.ravel(col_mat)]).T
rows, cols = zip(*points_arr)
res3[rows, cols] = X.flatten()
(res3==res1).all()
# True
```

The toy sample shown in above codes is to copy an array `X`'s value to another array `res` by coordinate-to-coordinate mapping. `res1` shows the `for` loop implementing this. We're all familiar with the expression commented with `====`, where continuous blocks' value can be jointly assigned (is it really "continuous" in memory?). However this is not applicable to enumerated index, as is shown in `res2`. `copy.deepcopy` doesn't work either.

Yes I've figured out a way to achieve this (as `res3`). First create meshgrid of indexed coordinates, and then use tuple indexing like assigning a long list of points.

But why? What's the `numpy` logic behind this? Are there any similar fallible points? Anyone who could explain this is appreciated!

Comment: `res2[indices, ...]` is a copy, not a view.

Comment: perhaps you mean a view, not a copy? but why res2[:n] and res2[indices] are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```py
res2[indices, ...][:, indices] = X
```

The part `res2[indices, ...]` creates a new array independent of `res2`, because you are using [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). The later bit `[:, indices] = X` will assign values to that new array, not to `res2`. To achieve what you want, you can use [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```py
res2[np.ix_(indices, indices)] = X
```